# Is there any thing which can be done only by Comparable and Comparator can't achieve the same

Tags: java, comparator, comparable

As I understand `Comparator` can do all that comparable does (+more) so, what is the need of having `Comparable`? Do we have any advantage in keeping `Comparable` in Java? Give one example such that something can only be done using `Comparable` and can't be done by using `Comparator`.

Comment: I implement Comparable when I want default sorting. Comparator for other sorting behaviors.

Comment: Think about the pain if some classes like String, Integer wouldn't implement Comparable. You would have to provide a custom comparator each time you want to store them in a TreeSet, use Collections.sort, etc.

Comment: @ZouZou Although not necessarily custom: a convention would probably arise that a class has a `Comparator<MyClass> NATURAL_ORDER` or similar. Not very convenient, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Comparable` is there to support the notion of a *natural order* for a class. Just like a class implements its *equality* semantics, so it can optionally implement its ordering semantics. These two notions are linked: the natural order should be *consistent with equals*, so it clearly belongs inside the same class.

Yes, we *could* manage without `Comparable`, at the expense of increased boilerplate where you couldn't even sort integers according to the obvious ordering without explicitly providing an ordering strategy.

Answer (score 4):

When a class implements `Comparable` you can sort collections of instances of this class without supplying a `Comparator` to the sort method. `Comparable` can be seen as the "natural" or default ordering of the class, while `Comparator`s allow you to define alternative orderings for the class.

For example, having `String` implement `Comparable<String>`, allows this code :

```
List<String> strings = ...
Collections.sort (strings);
```

which is simpler than this code :

```
List<String> strings = ...
Comparator<String> stringComparator = ...
Collections.sort (strings, stringComparator);
```

Comment: cant we use Comparator for natural ordering ?

Comment: we can, but how should the developers of string class implement a default ordering of strings without implementing the `compareTo()` method in string class. they can provide a `Comparator<String>` anywhere else, but this is not so clean as implementing an interface. You maybee should do a bit of research about interfaces than and their use.

Answer (score 0):

```
Comparable
```

A comparable object is capable of comparing itself with another object. The class itself must implements the java.lang.Comparable interface in order to be able to compare its instances.

```
Comparator
```

A comparator object is capable of comparing two different objects. The class is not comparing its instances, but some other class’s instances. This comparator class must implement the java.util.Comparator interface. - See more at: http://www.digizol.com/2008/07/java-sorting-comparator-vs-comparable.html#sthash.5ATshjUl.dpuf